# vim search with * regexp is not benefiting required results

Tags: vim

So, I think that my question is pretty simple, but still, i researched and didn't find an answer to it.

how can I use regexp, in particular * when searching in gvim?
for example, by searching **/abc*123** I hope to catch the following strings:

```
abc123

444abc000123

abcQQQ123WWW
```

as was expected by normal use of the * in regexp

I guess using * here is not working why is it? or it should be configed somehow in gvim config file?

thanks!

Comment: "as was expected by normal use of the * in regexp". Your expectation is wrong. In regular expressions `*` normally means zero or more times the previous character (as in the answer by @Light). This is not vim specific that is how regular expressions in general work. Your confusion may come from the fact that in file globbing `*` has the meaning you seem to expect, i.e. any character as in `*.txt`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
/abc.*123
```

`*` means matching any number of the char right before it. So `/abc*123` will match `abc123`, or `abcc123`, or `abccc123`, etc.

What you want to do is to match such a string that begins with `abc`, then any number of arbitrary characters, followed by `123`. Here use `.` to match ONE arbitrary character.

Comment: thank you for you detailed answer. issue is that when a line contais, for example _eeabccc111    lala a123ddd_, the vim marker is finding me the foillowing string ee**abccc111    lala a123**ddd. so how should spaces be ignored?

Comment: @AdiReiter To match a non space, use `\S`, thus `/abc\S*123`.